# Syntax and variables in Scheme

Tags: scheme

obviously, this code should fail :
`(define or 5)`

but I was wondering why does this code fail to run :

```
(define apply 
    (lambda (x y f)
        (f x y)
    )
)
(apply #f #t or)
```

`(or #f #t)`, would work as expected.

I'm not defining any new variable with a saved name, only passing the function  `or` as an argument.

and `(apply 1 2 +)` on the other hand works...

Comment: It is not obvious that `(define or 5)` fails. It does not make much sense, but it is legit Scheme code.

Comment: Also you should not name your function `apply`, that clashes with a built-in procedure of the same name.

Comment: Completely off topic: I personally didn't grok Scheme and Lisp until I gave up on the layout habits I had picked up from curly-brace languages. I think it's because they suggest (at least to me) a structure that doesn't fit reality.

Comment: It's not obvious that it should fail. Eg. `(define define 5)` is perfectly OK and in the same lexical scope you may not `define` anymore for anything other then getting the binding `5`.

Answer (score 3):

`or` is a special form. It isn't a function. So it can not be passed like that as an argument. Rather than `(apply #f #t or)`, you must use:

```
(apply #f #t (lambda (a b) (or a b)))
```

`(define or 5)` does not fail. It shadows the `or` special form. Some implementations may not allow redefinition either within a module or of given symbols. So when asking about Scheme it is important to specific the implementation.

This is because special forms can only occur in the first position. Special forms are implemented as macro expansions. For example: `(or a b)` => `(let ((v a)) (if v v b))`

Answer (score 1):

When you want to redefine special forms you need to use thunks, otherwise the arguments get evaluated, while the arguments of the special forms are evaluated in the order imposed inside the special form.

Instead, to get the same behavior as the semantics of the special forms you can force and delay the argument evaluation by using thunks. For example,

```
(define (or-sp-form a b) (if (a) 'ok (b)))
```

and call such a function like

```
(or-sp-form (lambda () false) (lambda () true))
```

Defining a special form like that, it can now be passed as argument to other functions like

```
(f or-sp-form)
```

and take care inside `f` to pass delayed arguments to `or-sp-form`.